# Cannot resolve method Placepicker.getPlace (context, intent)

Tags: android

An application based on Google API. When I try to use

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data)
```

There is an error showing:

```
cannot resolve method getPlace()
```

Comment: At least just try to get some solution over the internet and SO because there are so many posts available that help you to solve this error.

Comment: Saw your question on Android AJAX. You still need to solve it? `:)` Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This method is deprecated.
Use getPlace(Context, Intent) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax for the function

The actual syntax is

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, context);
```

You are using context,data parameters

> Example

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker) for more details

**Also make sure that you are importing the latest version of play-service to your application.**

For that follow these steps:

1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of
   play-services,

   `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1`
3. Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the
   google() repo or to

   `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`.
4. Save the changes, and click Sync Project with Gradle Files in the
   toolbar.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: As at 03/19, the documentation you linked actually states `PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();` which also exhibits the same `cannot resolve` error.